# Attached Properties throwing ParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I've followed the instruction from [Adding custom attributes to an element in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782864/wpf-xaml-custom-attribute-tags) but unfortunately the designer tells me that he can't find the element and when starting the program I get an XamlParserException with the message *Cannot set unknown member '{clr-namespace:myNs}MediaElementProperties.MediaId'*.

My Setup:

- Xaml-Page that is loaded dynamically with the command `XamlReader.Load(fileStream)` for displaying
- The content page itself which uses the code like this:

  ```
  <MediaElement myNs:MediaElementProperties.MediaId="test" ... />
  ```

  where myNs was defined with

  ```
   xmlns:myNs="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
  ```
- And the Definition of the MediaElementProperties which looks like this:

  ```
  namespace MyNamespace {
  public static class MediaElementProperties
  {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty MediaIdProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("MediaId", typeof(string), typeof(MediaElementProperties), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

      public static string GetMediaId(UIElement element)
      {
          return (string)element.GetValue(MediaIdProperty);
      }

      public static void SetMediaId(UIElement element, string value)
      {
          element.SetValue(MediaIdProperty, value);
      }
  }}
  ```

Do you have any ideas why I keep getting the exception?

Comment: Have you tried closing all designers, cleaning the solution and rebuilding it?

Comment: Have you tried `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached` instead of `DependencyProperty.Register`?

Comment: Tried it all. Didn't fix it. Designer still says that "The attachable Property MediaId was not found in type MediaElementProperties"

Comment: @AlexanderPacha: o.O, how did i not see this, you *absolutely have to* use `RegisterAttached`, if you still get an error that is caused by *something else*. (e.g. try adding the assembly to the xmlns again)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attached properties need to be registered with [`RegisterAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached.aspx) as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174610/attached-properties-throwing-parseexception#comment16296592_12174610) by [Zabavsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1199711/zabavsky).

When using the `XamlReader` you may need to be required to fully qualify your `xmlns`, even though the code is in the same assembly, i.e.

```
xmlns:myNs="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyApplication"
```

Comment: It's within the same application. I tried it, but it didn't solve it.