# Still can't use attached properties in silverlight for windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, properties

I'm a total noob with basic experience in javascript but really would like to learn c#net programming to make phone apps. The app I'm trying to do needs me to be able to set a custom property on certain xaml elements.

I found what seems to be a simple exemple of this on stackoverflow ([Adding custom attributes to an element in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782864/adding-custom-attributes-to-an-element-in-xaml)) and didn't get it work. I then read a lot of documentation everywhere and feel more confused than ever...I think I got the concept right, but my implementation is not. For exemple, if I just copy thecode from the page I mentionned, I get this:

Mainpage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" //<--ADDED BY ME
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"

shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->


    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
</Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyClass
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyProperty",
            typeof(string), typeof(MyClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static string GetMyProperty(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            return (string)element.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
        }
        public static void SetMyProperty(UIElement element, string value)
        {
            if (element == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            element.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

From there, I can't add any visual element because I have this error:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'FrameworkPropertyMetadata' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now, if this code worked, from what I understand, the attached property would only be avalaible to objetc of my class... How do you bind a xaml element and a c#class?

If you see where i'd like to go, any informatio you have will be appreciated. I already spent hours on this little detail...

Many thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!!!!!
(Yes, I'm a noob...I have some c#books ordered that are coming, I checked many sites but still nedd guidance..thanks again)

***EDIT:
Follow up: The suggestion given to me worked and let me compile but:***

The xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" gives me this error:

Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'MyNamespace' that is not included in the assembly. Do I need that line?

From there I can't add any other element. If I do remove that line, and add an ellipse, for exemple, I can't give it a MyProperty, VS tells me that :

The Property'MyProperty' was not found in type Ellipse.

I understand I registered 'MyProperty' for MyClass. Well, How do I give an Ellipse a class of 'MyClass'? Should I take another approach? Can I use 'MyProperty' on anything I want? Any tips highly appreciated, THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine for the most part.
You just need to change `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` to `PropertyMetadata`, and the code should compile just fine.

**Update:** The XAML namespace is actually wrong. You have defined MyNamespace inside the PhoneApp1 namespace. Therefore the complete namespace is PhoneApp1.MyNamespace

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneApp1.MyNamespace"
```

[This article has more on xaml namespaces in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Applying your attached property is simple enough once you have the namespace sorted. In fact, you have used an attached property already

> shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"

Your attached property will be applied like so:

```
<Grid local:MyClass.MyProperty="Value" />
```

[This article about Attached Properties should help](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Attached-Properties-in-Silverlight.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Thank you.Yes indeed just writing PropertyMetadata let me run the phone simulator. Strange since FrameWorkPropertyMetadata seemed to work in the post I mentionned.

Comment: THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR TIME!!!!! Seems like I owe you a beer or two...I can't believe it works now, since I spent so much time on it!! Thanks for the links too. I'm really grateful, thanks again...To have a working code will give me the confidence I need.

Comment: I must add for any noob like me who would need to read this post:       when you type a namespace, the declaration must be to the full left of the code. Any space between makes it invisible...