# Adding custom attributes with unique content

Tags: c#, wpf, attributes, dependency-properties, custom-attributes

I was looking for a way to add a custom property to a xaml control.

I found this solution: [Adding custom attributes to an element in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782985/1115471)

Not is my question: How can I permit only unique content (like the name Attribute)?

Comment: what you have tried? Update the sample in the question

Comment: @RameshMuthiah I have no idea ...

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: @RameshMuthiah I want to give different controls a "second name" (like the name attribute). The "second name" must always be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of the `attached properties` is "Allow different child elements to specify unique values for a property that is actually defined in a parent element"

Read "`Why Use Attached Properties`" section for better understanding. Hence we couldn't maintain the unique value

Ref :: [Link to Refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms749011.aspx)