# How do I set the aria-hidden attribute on a XAML form?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, .net-4.5, jaws-screen-reader

How do I set the [aria-hidden](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) attribute on a XAML form? More precisely, I need to set the aria-hidden attribute programmatically on the .xaml.cs file.

I need to set the aria-hidden to true because right now I have two interfaces overlapping, each one is hidden/disabled based on a drop-down box.

It all works correctly until it went through JAWS testing and the text-to-speech reader is reading the hidden field and hidden labels. After some research it appears as though I must set the aforementioned aria-hidden attribute to true when the fields are hidden to prevent the text-to-speech reader form reading them.

On the .xaml.cs form I'm hiding the fields on an event

```
this.myLabelForName.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

The this.myLabelForName does not a have a aria-hidden attribute.

I would like to set the aria-hidden to true because it would assist users. The aforementioned link states:

> "Authors MAY, with caution, use aria-hidden to hide visibly rendered
>   content from assistive technologies only if the act of hiding this
>   content is intended to improve the experience for users of assistive
>   technologies"

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5782985/3419825

Comment: @Balah Possibly, let me research this.